# PHP built-in web server is not finding assets

Tags: php, zend-framework2, assets, php-builtin-server

I have a php project built with Zend Framework 2. In want to start the built-in server to developing with the following command:

`sudo php -S localhost:8080 -t public/ public/index.php`

All the functionality of Zend Frameowrk 2 are working fine but I get 404 errors when retrieving the assets.

The assets are in the `public/css`, `public/img` and `public/js` folder.

`GET 
http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8080/css/dlu-tw-bootstrap.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 21ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8080/css/style.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 35ms]
GET 
http://localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 45ms]`

Any idea on how to allow the built-in server to access these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood from reading [this blog post](https://www.os-cms.net/blog/view/43/php-built-in-server-and-routing-static-content), you either need to start your command from the right folder and not specify any `-t` option

```
$ cd public
$ sudo php -S localhost:8080
```

Or you need to write your own routing rules in the `index.php`